# Determine where duplicate chars are in a string and add a hyphen between them

Tags: java, string

I know similar questions have been asked but no answer was sufficient to what I am trying to obtain. I would like to write a program that takes a string and passes that string to a method. Once it is passed to the method the method shall take that string search through it and find where duplicate chars appear and add a hyphen between them. I would only like to use the charAt(), length() and or substring() methods from the java api. Just to clarify, if the string"Hello" is passed to my method, then the method would return "Hel-lo". I have written up a little bit of code below.

```
public class SeperateDuplicates
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      System.out.println(seperateDuplicatesChars("Hello"));
      /*System.out.println(seperateDuplicatesChars("Bookkeeper"));
      System.out.println(seperateDuplicatesChars("Yellowwood door"));
      System.out.println(seperateDuplicatesChars("Chicago Cubs"));
      */
   }

   public static String seperateDuplicatesChars(String str)
   {
      char[] arr = new char[str.length()];

      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {
         arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
      }

      int counter = 0;

      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {
         counter++;
         if(arr[i] == arr[i+1])
         {
            counter++;
         }

      }


   }
```

}

Comment: @Yserbius  Not homework, newbie programmer to the java language and working on getting better at it, having trouble with strings. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Can you show us some of your work done on this.

Comment: @pro5476 You should read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) instead of calling others "rude" for enforcing the sites rules and guidelines - and you will probably get better results from your questions.

Answer (score 1):

In case you task it to modify a `String`, but `String` is inmodifiable in `java`, and each time when you insert or remove character from it, **a new string object** is created. That's why in genral case, to create new string you have to use `StringBuilder`. You can get more info from JavaDoc of this class.

```
public static String separateDuplicatesChars(String str) {
    if (str == null)
        return null;
    if (str.trim().isEmpty())
        return str;

    char prv = '\0';
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());


    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);

        if (prv == ch)
            buf.append('-');

        buf.append(ch);
        prv = ch;
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Or using `length()`, `charAt()` and `substring()` only:

```
public static String separateDuplicatesChars(String str) {
    if (str == null)
        return null;

    int size = str.length();
    int[] letters = new int[26];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        char base = ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' ? 'A' : ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' ? 'a' : '\0';

        if (base == '\0')
            continue;

        int letter = str.charAt(i) - base;

        if (letters[letter] != 0)
            size++;

        letters[letter]++;
    }

    char[] arr = new char[size];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < str.length(); i++, j++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);

        if (i > 0 && arr[i - 1] == ch)
            arr[j++] = '-';

        arr[j] = ch;
    }

    return new String(arr);
}
```

Comment: what about just using length(), charAt() and substring methods only

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Just create a new String which you will return and as you loop through your char array build it up. In the case your need to add a hyphen, just add it as well.